# Help required to set up multisite using organic groups (OG module)

Tags: organic-groups

I would like to create different multisite using organic groups in drupal. Each organic group would be a subdomain or domain. How can I achieve this functionality? I do not want to use domain access module.

What I exactly want is, when an organic group is created it should ask for the subdomain or domain and the user can enter the subdomain or domain which is to be associated to that organic group. Then when the user enters the subdomain.site.com the appropriate organic group should load. site admin associate to this organic group can login like this subdomain.site.com/user.

How can the above scenario achieved through organic groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have done it using Organic groups, spaces module and PURL.

1. First Install Spaces module after installing drupal
2. Then you can install PURL module and then organic groups module and OG theme module. OG theme associates theme to a group. You can also install OG menu if needed.
3. Once PURL is installed, go to admin/config/search/purl/types, enable subdomain option and domain option if needed.
4. Now create a content type of Group type or install OG example module (it automatically creates a organic group content type)
5. Now create a node which is of type group - node/add/group
6. Fill in the options and enter the Subdomain. For the subdomain to work you should have added ServerAlias *.site.com in your httpd.conf file
7. Once the node of type group is created your minisite is ready.
8. Using OG theme you can associate a separate theme for your organic group created.
9. Using og menu you can associate a separate menu for your organic group.

Comment: You should add some detail (e.g. how it was configured). Self answered questions are encouraged here, but telling someone "just use this module" doesn't explain how it solved your question.

Comment: @ShawnConn ok done.!